# One website - Multiple Store Catalog Search Frontend Problem

Tags: products, catalogsearch

I am setting one website - multiple store website. My issue on catalog search on front end, when i search from any item in particular store then it returns other store products also.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add products to `store groups`. You can only assign `products` to `websites`.for  store you add `categories` based `product`..

Comment: yes right i setup all things. Products display accordng to categories. But in front end catalog search why both store products are coming.

Comment: it is magento bug. i think core hack and set the store filter on product collection..